# local storage: add a Map<String,String> to a stored List

Tags: dart, local-storage

I'm trying to store tasks using local storage.

This is my function:

```dart
void saveTask(_) {
    String sum = querySelector('#tsummary').value;
    String con = querySelector('#tcontent').value;
    String sched = querySelector('#dateinp').value;
    String timestamp = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    Storage localStorage = window.localStorage;
    var dt = localStorage['darttasks'];

    if (dt == null) {
    localStorage['darttasks'] = JSON.encode([]);
    }
    var task = {"summary":sum, "content" :con,"scheduled":sched, "id":timestamp};
    localStorage['darttasks'] = JSON.encode(JSON.decode(localStorage['darttasks']).add(task));
}
```

This fails however, with the following error message:

Exception: The null object does not have a method 'add'.

> NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'add' Receiver: null Arguments:
>   [Instance of '_LinkedHashMap']

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your last lines encodes `void`. The .add function of a list returns void. Here's an updated version:

```dart
final String STORAGE_KEY = 'darttasks';
List tasks = [];
if(window.localStorage.containsKey(STORAGE_KEY)) {
  tasks = JSON.decode(window.localStorage[STORAGE_KEY]);

  // Decoding Error, should not happen
  if(tasks == null) {
    tasks = [];
  }
}

var task = {
  "summary": sum,
  "content": con,
  "scheduled": sched,
  "id": timestamp
};
tasks.add(task);
window.localStorage[STORAGE_KEY] = JSON.encode(tasks);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm an idiot. This is unfortunately not the first time I stumbled over something like this.

Comment: If this solves your problem, can you please accept the answer?